# featuretools: How to properly generate features for a regression task

Tags: featuretools

I want to try featuretools, but I need a hint, how can I use for my dataset. I have data in the pandas dataframe, and it is a regression problem.

Here is an example of my dataset:
[image]

What did I try:

```
import featuretools as ft
es = ft.EntitySet(id = 'train_X')
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="train_X",
                                  dataframe=X,
                                  index="Index",
                        variable_types={
 "Market": ft.variable_types.Categorical,
 "Stock": ft.variable_types.Categorical,}
                                 )

feature_matrix_customers, features_defs = ft.dfs(entities=es,
                                           target_entity="y")
```

And got an error:

```
 KeyError: 'Entity 0 does not exist in train_X').
```

Comment: have you tried the getting started guide in the documentation? https://docs.featuretools.com/#minute-quick-start. let us know if there's any specific place you're hitting issues or have confusions.

Comment: @MaxKanter sure, I updated my question.

Comment: the target entity should be the ID you provide above. Try setting it to `train_X`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is likely that you’re trying to use a pandas dataframe directly as the input rather than an loading your data into an EntitySet. You should instead create an [EntitySet](https://docs.featuretools.com/loading_data/using_entitysets.html) and build features for that. You can also use `EntitySet.enormalize_entity(...)` with that `EntitySet` to create other entities to aid feature engineering.

As a note: You will probably want to look into use [cutoff_times](https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/handling_time.html) with this data type, which will allow you to specify which data can and can’t be used for generating features.

Comment: please check my question once again.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
feature_matrix_customers, features_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es, entities=es, target_entity="train_X")
```